# Checking the value of 4 input boxes simultaneously instead of one-by-one

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can the code below be modified, such that I would be able to check the value and add a class to the 4 input boxes if my validate_date(date) is false, simultaneously as opposed to checking each field one-by-one, exiting the function each and every time as its current setup is?

I am using some jQuery, so I am jQuery friendly

```
date1 = document.getElementById('date1').value
if (date1) {
    if (validate_date(date1) == true) {
        date1 = parseDate(date1)
    } else {
        $("#date1").addClass("invalid")
        return
    }
} else {
    date1 = null
}
date2 = document.getElementById('date2').value
if (date2) {
    if (validate_date(date2) == true) {
        date2 = parseDate(date2)
    } else {
        $("#date2").addClass("invalid")
        return
    }
} else {
    date2 = null
}
date3 = document.getElementById('date3').value
if (date3) {
    if (validate_date(date3) == true) {
        date3 = parseDate(date3)
    } else {
        $("#date3").addClass("invalid")
        return
    }
} else {
    date3 = null
}
date4 = document.getElementById('date4').value
if (date4) {
    if (validate_date(date4) == true) {

        date4 = parseDate(date4)
    } else {
        $("#date4").addClass("invalid")
        return
    }
} else {
    date4 = null
}
function validate_date(str) {
    var t = str.match(/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/);
    if (t === null) return false;
    var d = parseInt(t[1]),
        m = parseInt(t[2], 10),
        y = parseInt(t[3], 10);
    //below should be more acurate algorithm
    if (m >= 1 && m <= 12 && d >= 1 && d <= 31) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The easiest way to validate a date in JS is to attempt to make a Date object from the input string. While your regex `var t = str.match(/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/)` accepts things like `03/04/2014` (exactly 2-digit mm dd and only slash separators) trying `new Date(str)` will accept all of these: `12/4/1961`, `1944-12-7`, `7-Feb-1927`, `July 4, 1776` giving your user more flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/RqyDT/1/

**HTML:**

```
<form class="validation" action="your_page.html">
<p>
    <label for="date1">Date 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="date1" class="date"/>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="date2">Date 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="date2" class="date"/>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="date1">Date 3</label>
    <input type="text" name="date3" class="date"/>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="date2">Date 4</label>
    <input type="text" name="date4" class="date"/>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</p>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.invalid{color:red;}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function validate_date(str) {
    var t = str.match(/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/);
    if (t === null) return false;
    var d = parseInt(t[1]),
        m = parseInt(t[2], 10),
        y = parseInt(t[3], 10);
    //below should be more acurate algorithm
    if (m >= 1 && m <= 12 && d >= 1 && d <= 31) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".validation").submit(function(){
      //Initialize
      var valid_fields = true;
      $('label').removeClass("invalid");

      //Loop through date input
      $(".date").each(function(){
          var date_val = $(this).val();

          //If validation function return false, add class "invalid" to the label
          if (validate_date(date_val) == false) {
              $('label[for="'+ $(this).attr('name') +'"]').addClass('invalid');
              valid_fields = false;
          }
      });

      //Return true or false, depends of the form validation
      return valid_fields;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little confusing, as such I made some quick adjustments as I'm unsure if you're using a framework. Here is a basic model of what I believe you are asking. it will look for elements with the ids "date1", "date2"... until it gets to date4 and will stop. For each element it gets the value, validates the value, if valid it parses it and sets that data into the value of the parent element. Otherwise it adds the "invalid" class. Was unsure what the else on the if(value) clause was supposed to do, but I did kept it there in case you were doing something farther down that I was unaware of.

Another way would be to check elements by tag name and filter out ones with the name/id value that contains "date" but i figured this was more direct.

```
var base = 'date';

for(var i=1;i<=4;i++)}

    var el = document.getElementById(base+i);
    var value = el.value;
    if (value) {
        if (validate_date(value) == true) {
            el.value = parseDate(value)
        } else {
            el.className = (el.className.length > 0) ? el.className + " invalid" : "invalid";
        }
    } else {
        el.value = "";
    }

}
```